# Help finding early American horror story

Tags: story-identification, horror

Could someone point me to the short story from approximately the early 20th century - I'd say 1910s or 1920s - about a man who has his arms and legs amputated at the order of an Indian rajah and manages to take revenge?

Comment: Does this story has science-fiction or fantasy elements? Could you take a look [at this page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info) and [add more detail](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/154934/edit) to your question?

Comment: What sort of revenge?

Comment: I do not believe it is science fictional at all, but the story is "His Unconquerable Enemy" by W. C. Morrow.  You can read it here https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiatq2xtd7SAhUH3IMKHUxRBD4QFghDMAc&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.vb-tech.co.za%2Febooks%2FMorrow%2520WC%2520-%2520His%2520Unconquerable%2520Enemy%2520-%2520HO.pdf&usg=AFQjCNElRSK_Wz3X8HkqshpqP9PP-DMQ5A&sig2=8Gqs8Y6lirqKxOB1mV_sDQ

Comment: Many thanks, you've nailed it. I think it fits under fantasy if your definition is flexible.

Comment: @OrganicMarble It is Speculative Fiction.. It's in the [ISFDB](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?86583), it was reprinted in [*Weird Tales*](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?61892+c). The story is available at [Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/21616).

Comment: @Adamant, Gallifreyan, Mooz, Blackwood: "This question does not appear to be about **science fiction or fantasy within the scope defined in the help center.**" Really? I've never been able to find a definition of "science fiction or fantasy" in the help center.